# Simple database design - store messages

Tags: database-design

I want to design a simple database which contains messages.  Each message has a Category.  Each message can have one or more Subcategories, but it may not have a subcategory at all.

**CategoryTable**
CategoryKey,
Category

**SubCategoryTable**
SubCategoryKey,
CategoryKey,
SubCategory,

**MessageTable**
MessageKey,
SubCategoryKey,
Message,

The problem with this design is that if a Message Category has no subcategory, how can I retrieve the messages for that Category?

Whats the best approach for this? Should I have a "None" Subcategory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Message Table so it points to the Category table.

```
MessageTable
------------
MessageKey
CategoryKey
Message
```

Add a MessageSubcategory Table for the one or more sub categories a message might have.

```
MessageSubCategoryTable
-----------------------
MessageKey
SubCategoryKey
```

You can get any SubCategories with the following psudeo-SQL:

```
Select Subcategory
From SubCategoryTable, MessageSubCategoryTable
Where CategoryKey = CategoryKey from MessageTable 
And SubCategoryKey = SubCategoryKey from MessageSubCategoryTable
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  So what would the pseudo-SQL be to select all the messages for a given Category? SELECT Message FROM MessageTable WHERE Category = "MyCategory" AND SubCategory = ?

Comment: anyone have an answer to my query?

Comment: For a given Category the psuedo-SQL would be SELECT Message FROM MessageTable WHERE Category = "MyCategory".  If you want to include the sub categories, the psuedo-SQL would be SELECT Message FROM MessageTable WHERE Category = "MyCategory" & SELET Subcategory FROM SubcategoryTable WHERE Category = "MyCategory"

Comment: subcategory table does not have a Category field, it does however have the Category Key.   If for example, the Category was 'Birthday' and it has a subcategory (30th, 40th, 50th etc).  Then how would I bring back all messages where the Category is 'Birthday' and the SubCategory is '60th'??

Comment: This works, although might be tricky to maintain if I insert new messages I will need to also insert into the subcategory table...